# VBA - msgbox when file not found

Tags: vba, excel

I want a msgbox to show "File not found" when the file TestData.xlsx is not found. Thanks

```
Sub check()
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> From Row 5 to row 10
    '~~> Chnage as applicable
    For i = 5 To 10
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Formula = _
        "=VLookup((CONCATENATE(C1,"" "",C" & i & _
        ")),'C:\Documents[TestData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$G$28,7, FALSE)"

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10):

Do a check for the file before your for loop:

```
If Dir$("C:\Documents\TestData.xlsx") = "" Then
    MsgBox "File not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
Sub test()

    sPath = "C:\Documents\TestData.xlsx"

     'Test if directory or file exists
    If File_Exists(sPath) Then
        MsgBox sPath & " exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox sPath & " does not exist."
    End If

End Sub

Private Function File_Exists(ByVal sPathName As String,
    Optional Directory As Boolean) As Boolean

    'Returns True if the passed sPathName exist
    'Otherwise returns False
    On Error Resume Next
    If sPathName <> "" Then
        If IsMissing(Directory) Or Directory = False Then
            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName) <> "")
        Else
            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName, vbDirectory) <> "")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This is from the second google result of "vba test if file exists" http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/04/vba-function-to-check-file-existence.html

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

[image: Menu Path]
[image: ReferenceWindow]

and then:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Not fso.FileExists("C:\Documents\TestData.xlsx") Then MsgBox "File Not Found."
```

Comment: Why call another dll? If the task could be accomplished just using ``FileLen`` or ``Dir`` inbuilt functions?

Comment: I guess it's preference in this instance, but I find the `FileSystemObject` a very handy tool all-around, so I end up using it for all file-related tasks.  The code is more self-descriptive too: `Dir$` vs. `.FileExists`, which one _sounds_ more like you're checking for file existence?  :)

Comment: Late response but, +1 for your comment. Though personally, I prefer to use latebinding if I use external resources since often these things get passed around the office and I've been burned too many times by people having a slightly older version of the dll so the reference cannot be found etc. `Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`